# conversion of jpeg picture to pdf file

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert a set of jpeg images into a pdf file (which should contain all the jpeg).
I want to do it in .Net1.1 and programatically in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to create the pdf and add images to it. Here's a [sample](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap0602.cs).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) - it's a wrapper around ImageMagick, which can convert pretty much anything into anything. (I've only used the command line tool.)

If there's a problem with support for older .NET versions, just execute the command line tool yourself - it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of them open source pdf library - http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Please try [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) in order to either [convert the images to PDF file](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/working-with-images-1.html) or [add images to an existing PDF file](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/add-image-in-an-existing-pdf-file.html). This works with .NET 1.1 and above. You can use it in any of your .NET applications using C# or VB.NET. It works on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems alike. Please try the component at your end.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.